# Select count from multiple tabes

Tags: sql

I have three tables TableThreeItems, TableTwoItems and TableOneItems, I need to get the number of visits that Person had in each of these tables.

I tried the following :

```
SELECT Person.[PersonId]

,  Count(TableOneItemId ) as TableOneItemCount
, Count(TableTwoItemIdId ) as TableTwoItemCount
, Count(TableThreeItemId )  as TableThreeItemCount


FROM  [dbo].[Person]
LEFT JOIN TableOneItem ON TableOneItem.PersonId=Person.PersonId
LEFT JOIN TableThreeItemId ON TableThreeItemId.PersonId=Person.PersonId
LEFT JOIN TableTwoItemId ON TableTwoItemId.PersonId=Person.PersonId
WHERE [Person].PersonId=1
GROUP BY Person.[PersonId]
```

But this doesn't consider the count of each of these as separate but i'm always a wrong count. For example, if he had 1 TableOneItem and 2 TableTwoItemIds, the TableOneItemCount would be 2 while the TableTwoItemIdCount is 2

Comment: Can you add sample data in your table and what output you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a single `join` by using `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT Person.[PersonId], 
       Count(distinct TableOneItemId ) as TableOneItemCount,
       Count(distinct TableTwoItemIdId ) as TableTwoItemCount,
       Count(distinct TableThreeItemId )  as TableThreeItemCount
FROM  [dbo].[Person] LEFT JOIN
      TableOneItem
      ON TableOneItem.PersonId = Person.PersonId LEFT JOIN
      TableThreeItemId
      ON TableThreeItemId.PersonId = Person.PersonId LEFT JOIN
      TableTwoItemId
      ON TableTwoItemId.PersonId = Person.PersonId
WHERE [Person].PersonId = 1
GROUP BY Person.[PersonId];
```

This is not recommended if you expect the counts to be even moderately large.  If the counts are each 100, then this produces a cartesian product for each person with 100*100*100 = 1,000,000 intermediate rows.  Way too much processing.  In that case, you want to do the counts as a subquery.

```
SELECT Person.[PersonId], TableOneItemCount, TableTwoItemCount, TableThreeItemCount
FROM  [dbo].[Person] LEFT JOIN
      (select personid, count(TableOneItemId) as TableOneItemCount from TableOneItem where PersonId = 1 group by personid
      ) t1
      ON t1.PersonId = Person.PersonId LEFT JOIN
      (select personid, count(TableTwoItemId) as TableTwoItemCount from TableTwoItem where PersonId = 1 group by personid
      ) t2
      ON t2.PersonId = Person.PersonId LEFT JOIN
      (select personid, count(TableThreeItemId) as TableThreeItemCount from TableThreeItem where PersonId = 1 group by personid
      ) t3
      ON t3.PersonId = Person.PersonId
WHERE Person.PersonId = 1;
```

In most cases, you would just use `group by PersonId` in the subqueries for the calculation without the `where`.  But you are only selecting one person.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a `DISTINCT` to the count and you're done:

```
SELECT Person.[PersonId]

,  Count(DISTINCT TableOneItemId ) as TableOneItemCount
, Count(DISTINCT TableTwoItemIdId ) as TableTwoItemCount
, Count(DISTINCT TableThreeItemId )  as TableThreeItemCount


FROM  [dbo].[Person]
LEFT JOIN TableOneItem ON TableOneItem.PersonId=Person.PersonId
LEFT JOIN TableThreeItemId ON TableThreeItemId.PersonId=Person.PersonId
LEFT JOIN TableTwoItemId ON TableTwoItemId.PersonId=Person.PersonId
WHERE [Person].PersonId=1
GROUP BY Person.[PersonId]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Person.[PersonId]

,  (SELECT Count(TableOneItemId ) from TableOneItem where TableOneItem.PersonId=Person.PersonId) as TableOneItemCount
,  (SELECT Count(TableTwoItemId ) from TableTwoItem where TableTwoItem.PersonId=Person.PersonId) as TableTwoItemCount
,  (SELECT Count(TableThreeItemId ) from TableThreeItem where TableThreeItem.PersonId=Person.PersonId) as TableThreeItemCount

FROM  [dbo].[Person]
WHERE [Person].PersonId=1
```

Answer (score 0):

`join`ing will create a line for each combination, and the grouping will only be applied afterwards. So, as you noted, this will not generate the correct output. One trick is to perform the grouping and the counting **before** you join:

```
SELECT    Person.[PersonId], TableOneItemCount, TableTwoItemCount, TableThreeItemCount
FROM      Person
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   PersonId, COUNT(*) AS TableOneItemCount
           FROM     TableOneItem
           GROUP BY PersonId) t1 ON p.PersonId = t1.PersonId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   PersonId, COUNT(*) AS TableTwoItemCount
           FROM     TableTwoItem
           GROUP BY PersonId) t2 ON p.PersonId = t2.PersonId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   PersonId, COUNT(*) AS TableThreeItemCount
           FROM     TableThreeItem
           GROUP BY PersonId) t3 ON p.PersonId = t3.PersonId
WHERE     [Person].PersonId = 1
```

Comment: You're effectively filtering on the PeronsId in the join condition.. you don't need to `group by`. Also, you should account for nulls in the outer select. ie. `SELECT Person.[PersonId], COALESCE(TableOneItemCount,0) TableOneItemCount, COALESCE(TableTwoItemCount,0) TableTwoItemCount, COALESCE(TableThreeItemCount,0) TableThreeItemCount`